# Set Pandas Data Frame elements to 0 if corresponding element is False

Tags: replace, pandas, boolean, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df0:
A  B  C
x  y  z
m  n  o
h  i  j

df1:
False False False
False True False
False False False
```

I want to get a "." only when the corresponding element in df1 is True:

```
df0:
A  B  C
.  .  .
.  n  .
.  .  .
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [pandas.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking):

```
In [139]: df0 = pd.DataFrame([list('xyz'),list('mno'),list('hij')], columns=list('ABC'))
In [143]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([(False,False,False),(False,True,False),(False,False,False)])
In [153]: df0.where(df1.values, other='.')
Out[153]: 
   A  B  C
0  .  .  .
1  .  n  .
2  .  .  .

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: What if I want to change the df0 values based on df1 first column only booleans?